# write to stdout with win32 gui app

Tags: winapi, user-interface, stdio

If a win32 GUI app is run from the command line 
      e.g gfxexe.exe

first what is the simplest way to detect that it has been run from a command line
(cmd32.exe and possible other 3rd part command line apps).

second, and most importantly, if the app has been launched from the command line, how
can i print something to it.. e.g , this app can't be run from a command line.

Comment: what's the intent? a started process is a started process...

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Method I could come up with is. First, Create a console application, then Have your console application spawn your Window application, and Finally, Use Mapped Memory or some other form  of Inter-Process Communication.